# Browserify transform with reactify

Tags: reactjs, gulp, browserify, watchify, reactify

I am trying to build a project using gulp. Unfortunately I am experiencing some trouble with it.

This is what my gulpfile.js looks like:

```
'use strict';

var watchify = require('watchify');
var browserify = require('browserify');
var gulp = require('gulp');
var source = require('vinyl-source-stream');
var buffer = require('vinyl-buffer');
var gutil = require('gulp-util');
var sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
var assign = require('lodash.assign');
var reactify = require('reactify');

// add custom browserify options here
var customOpts = {
  entries: ['./js/app.js'],
  debug: true
};
var opts = assign({}, watchify.args, customOpts);
var b = watchify(browserify(opts)); 
b.transform(reactify);

// add transformations here
// i.e. b.transform(coffeeify);

gulp.task('js', bundle); // so you can run `gulp js` to build the file
b.on('update', bundle); // on any dep update, runs the bundler
b.on('log', gutil.log); // output build logs to terminal

function bundle() {

  return b.bundle()
    // log errors if they happen
    .on('error', gutil.log.bind(gutil, 'Browserify Error'))
    .pipe(source('bundle.js'))
    // optional, remove if you don't need to buffer file contents
    .pipe(buffer())
    // optional, remove if you dont want sourcemaps
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init({loadMaps: true})) // loads map from browserify file
       // Add transformation tasks to the pipeline here.
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./')) // writes .map file
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./js/build'));
}
```

The problem is that gulp is displaying an error indicating that some third party library has somewhere the illegal token '<' the file in question is written in the JSX syntax.

Yet, I don't have the problem when I run the following command:

```
browserify -g reactify js\app.js > js\build\bundle.js
```

Please, what is wrong with my gulpfile?

Thanks in advance to anybody seeking to help!

**Edit:** I suspect that the -g option makes it transform the jsx recursively to plain javascript, I'm trying to find out an equivalent in the watchify.transform function, unsuccessfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the [docs for `.transform`](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify#btransformtr-opts) say:

> If opts.global is true, the transform will operate on ALL files, despite whether they exist up a level in a node_modules/ directory

So to replicate `-g reactify`, you'd do

```
b.transform(reactify, {global: true});
```

Keep in mind however that I would consider the fact that you need `-g` to be a bug in whatever dependency node_module you are referring to. Generally modules should include browserify config params in their own `package.json` file so that you don't have to configure it globally. As the next part of those docs say:

> Use global transforms cautiously and sparingly, since most of the time an ordinary transform will suffice.

Comment: Worked perfectly, thanks a lot!
Yes, I targeted the module, I will raise the issue to its maintainers.

Answer (score 1):

Better to use Babel it supports `JSX` as well.

https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/jsx/

Comment: Never heard about, seems cool but I don't see why is it better to use. Any particular interresting feature?

Comment: Yes. While it will transpile JSX just like React-Tools, it also transpiles ES6, so you can use arrow functions, classes and more.

Comment: Browserify also seems to include an ES6 transpiler https://www.npmjs.com/package/browserify-es6-transpiler
But thanks for the suggestion ;)